# Node Js asyncronic mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

I´m trying to do an asynchronous query in NodeJS but keep getting `undefined` as a result, my code is:

```
async function Nuevo_Parametro() {
  sqlStr = "select * from Parametros limit 10";
  conCasos.query(sqlStr, function(err, Resultado, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return Resultado;
  });
}

Nuevo_Parametro().then(Resultado => {
  console.log(Resultado);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you're mixing callback styles with Promises. The `mysql` function does not return a Promise, so you can't concatenate it. It uses a callback style - meaning the "async" part is executed in that callback you provide as a  parameter.
What you need to do is wrap it up with a Promise and return that. Something along the lines of the following

```
function Nuevo_Parametro() {
  sqlStr="select * from Parametros limit 10"
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conCasos.query(sqlStr, function(err, Resultado,fields) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      };
      resolve(Resultado);
    })
  })
}
Nuevo_Parametro().then(Resultado => {
  console.log(Resultado)
})
```

Here we return a promise we're creating, and in the callback `query` offers, I'm resolving it. I kept the variables and property names as they are for simplicity.

If you're going to use extensively the queries, perhaps it might be tedious to be `new`ing promises everytime, so as it's mentioned in this [github ticket](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1755) you can use a wrapper [like this one](https://github.com/CodeFoodPixels/node-promise-mysql)

or maybe use the native `promisify` utility as [this comment states](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1755#issuecomment-345459882)

```
const fn = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);
const rows = await fn('SELECT col1, col2 FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email]);
```